# How to resolve tag name collisions for multiple tools of same name?

Tags: support, tags, tag-disambiguation

I've started using a command line tool recently in shell named `yq` which as of this writing has 22 questions tagged [yq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yq). I got to know that there are two versions of this YAML parser standardized (See [Naming collision in package yq](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/29529))

1. [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq)
2. [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq)

Quick glance at the questions suggested that the question authors are not seemingly differentiating between the versions they are using. I fear this could cause more confusion when the tag gets a bit more popular than now.

How should this tag be handled? As a regular watcher of the tags should I insist the authors to explicitly mention the version they are using and keep the same tag yq or we need to create separate tags for this? I'll update the tag wiki based on the inputs I get from this post.

Comment: [kislyuk-yq] and [mikefarah-yq]. Debian way, baby.

Answer (score 3):

May I formally propose Braiam's suggestion of splitting it into tags kislyuk-yq and mikefarah-yq? This remains a confusing and surprising situation and while I don't think it's ever going to stop being confusing, and I suspect the yq tag will keep coming back, we can at least make the existing questions a bit less confusing.